# Different result HMAC SHA-256 in C++ and PHP

Tags: php, c++, openssl, sha256, hmac

I encode string to base64 and generate HMAC SHA256 with this base64 string.  I encode the result of HMAC(char bytes) to base64.

I use C++: openssl library.

And got a different results in PHP and C++:

**C++:**

`JSON: {"req_hash":"someUniqCodeHash","answer":true}`

`BASE64: eyJyZXFfaGFzaCI6InNvbWVVbmlxQ29kZUhhc2giLCJhbnN3ZXIiOnRydWV9`

`HMAC: P/p2YlxL8xdhmn+QIAlVLFDS50ai4JE/l1pMMrKZKrE=`

**PHP:**

`JSON: {"req_hash":"someUniqCodeHash","answer":true}`

`BASE64: eyJyZXFfaGFzaCI6InNvbWVVbmlxQ29kZUhhc2giLCJhbnN3ZXIiOnRydWV9`

`HMAC: P/p2YlxL8xdhmn+QIAlVLFDS50ai4JE/l1pMMrKZKrE=`

And if you can see, **HMAC same result**!

`c++: P/p2YlxL8xdhmn+QIAlVLFDS50ai4JE/l1pMMrKZKrE=`

`php: P/p2YlxL8xdhmn+QIAlVLFDS50ai4JE/l1pMMrKZKrE=`

**But, when I change JSON like this (changed `true` to `false`)**:

`JSON: {"req_hash":"someUniqCodeHash","answer":false}`

i got this:

**C++:**

`JSON: {"req_hash":"someUniqCodeHash","answer":false}`

`BASE64: eyJyZXFfaGFzaCI6InNvbWVVbmlxQ29kZUhhc2giLCJhbnN3ZXIiOmZhbHNlfQ==`

`HMAC: znUOWS2MMLpjIBSpq2GfSNivaL8IUDcZXZs24D0=`

**PHP:**

`JSON: {"req_hash":"someUniqCodeHash","answer":false}`

`BASE64: eyJyZXFfaGFzaCI6InNvbWVVbmlxQ29kZUhhc2giLCJhbnN3ZXIiOmZhbHNlfQ==`

`HMAC: znUOWS2MMLpjIBSpq2GfSNivaL8IUDcZXZs24D0AHZA=`

**Why the HMAC result is different?**

You can see:

`C++: znUOWS2MMLpjIBSpq2GfSNivaL8IUDcZXZs24D0=`

`PHP: znUOWS2MMLpjIBSpq2GfSNivaL8IUDcZXZs24D0AHZA=`

In PHP HMAC string added some chars: `...AHZA=`. 
**What is this?**

And my **PHP code**:

```
 <?php
 $b = base64_encode('{"req_hash":"someUniqCodeHash","answer":false}');
 $hmac =$b.".".base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',$b,'eyJhZGRyZXNzX3RvIjp7JzEnOidjbGll',true));
```

My **C++ code**:

```
std::string sfjson = "{\"req_hash\":\"someUniqCodeHash\",\"answer\":false}";
std::cout << "JSON: " << sfjson << "\n";

std::string fencoded_data = base64_encode_str(sfjson);
std::cout << "BASE64: " << fencoded_data << "\n";

unsigned char* digest;
std::string key = "eyJhZGRyZXNzX3RvIjp7JzEnOidjbGll";

digest = HMAC(EVP_sha256(), reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(key.c_str()), key.length(), reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(fencoded_data.c_str()), fencoded_data.length(), NULL, NULL);

std::string sName(reinterpret_cast<char*>(digest));

std::string hmac_data = base64_encode_str(sName);

std::cout << "HMAC: " << hmac_data << "\n";
```

Base64 from there: https://gist.github.com/rustem-art/5f6b510c65bbbfd279386225b978f960

Comment: Based on the fact that the difference is just the trailing part, I'm going to assume that PHP and C++ are using a different padding. Not sure how it's different but I think that's the direction to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! ;)

Never use NULL as:

```
digest = HMAC(EVP_sha256(),
              reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(key.c_str()), key.length(),
              reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data.c_str()), data.length(),
              NULL, NULL);
```

Use special variable (in my code is: diglen and result) for return function.

```
unsigned int diglen;

unsigned char result[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];

digest = HMAC(EVP_sha256(),
              reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(key.c_str()), key.length(),
              reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data.c_str()), data.length(),
              result, &diglen);
```